# How to handle conflicts when working with two codebases with different pojos in absence of version control

Tags: hibernate, version-control

So I and my teammate both work on the same project and doing by editing the same codebase. We don't use version control.

Our team had a plan of using SVN but scrapped for some reason. We are using Hibernate 3.1 (without annotations) with J2EE 1.4. The manager gives me some task that I finish working on in my local machine. Now I am required to work on my teammates codebase which he edited from original.

So I have to include all the files related to a use case in my eclipse workspace. In addition to code changes, there are different setters/getters (same function but different name) for mappings used by both of us.

How would I automate all these changes into one place? Which version control software do I start with that will have *lowest* learning curve? How do I standardize POJO getter/setter in my model? I'm really lost and  would appreciate any help!

Comment: Git is becoming the de-facto standard, but although more powerful, it's also harder to learn and use than SVN. I would go with Git. This is something you should learn anyway, whatever the time it takes. If you have two fields to represent the same thing, then choose the one which has the best name, and remove the other one.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Started with svn, hope it will be sufficient for now.